# How should the error in the root directory cluster settings of Apache IoTDB Version 0.13 be solved?

Tags: directory, cluster-computing, apache-iotdb, iotdb

mvn clean package -pl cluster -am -DskipTests

[Error] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: cluster @

I was following the tutorial user guide on cluster settings of Apache IoTDB Version 0.13. When I entered "mvn clean package -pl cluster -am -DskipTests" command into IoTDB root directory, like the tutorial suggested, an error occured: [Error] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: cluster @. How should this error be handled?

How to deal this question ? Someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

Apache IoTDB Version 0.13 is not a version that completed a stabilized cluster version. Therefore constructing cluster architecture from this version is not recommended.

Instead, you can try to update to 1.0 cluster version, that already forms the distributed architecture of all writing, querying, and computing operations.